# Angular How Can I add Multiple Objects instead of overwriting to localStorage

Tags: angular, typescript

When submitting a form, I am saving data to localeStorage, but when I submit form again it overwrites data, how can I add another object to it?

**.ts**

```
    this.formAlias = 'addBeneficiary';
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[ა-ჰ\-\s]+$')]],
      surname: ['', [Validators.required,  Validators.pattern('[ა-ჰ\-\s]+$')]],
      personalNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'), Validators.minLength(11), Validators.maxLength(11)]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'), Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(11), Validators.required]],
    });
    
      onSubmit() {
        this.submitted$.next(true);
        if (this.form.valid) {
          setToLocalStorage('policy', this.formAlias, this.form.value);
          this.stepService.nextStep();
        } else {
              this.submitted = true;
            }
      }

//setToLocalStorage 

    export const setToLocalStorage = (storageKey: string, key: string, value: any) =>
        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify({
            ...getFromLocalStorage(storageKey),
            [key]: value
        }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the array of values in the local storage. So that on each submit you can read the array from local storage, add the form value and save the updated array,

```js
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted$.next(true);
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const formValuesArray: Array<any> = getFromLocalStorage('policy') || [];
      formValuesArray.push(this.form.value);
      setToLocalStorage('policy', this.formAlias, formValuesArray);
      this.stepService.nextStep();
    } else {
      this.submitted = true;
    }
  }
```

I don't know how is the `setToLocalStorage` method is implemented as it looks like a custom code. Adding its code to the question might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i edited my answer and added my setToLocalStorage method.

Comment: i get error in my code: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'unknown'. any ideas?

Comment: it should be because the method `getFromLocalStorage` return type is `unknown`. That is reasonable. I updated the code sample with the typings for the `formValuesArray` variable

Comment: in my policy value there are many objects: like this
 {
    "calculatorInfo": {
        "product": "lifeci",
        "gender": "F",
        "payFrequency": 12,
        "subLimit": "100",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "amount": "25000",
        "period": 7
    },
    "contactInfo": {
        "email": "fvreferf@gmail.com",
        "phone": "568552211",
        "termsConditions": true
    },
    "beneficiaryInfo": {
        "name": "ლიკა",
        "surname": "ტყჰტჰტჰყტჰტ",
        "personalNumber": "02027041738",
        "phone": "568552255"
    }
}

Comment: and i get this error: ERROR TypeError: formValuesArray.push is not a function

Comment: i tried like this:
const formValuesArray: Array<any> = getFromLocalStorage(JSON.stringify('policy')) || [];
but it still overwrites data

Answer (score 0):

As said by @IAfanasov you can store the values as arrays. Another way this can be achieved is to simply create unique keys... and luckily from your code I can guess that  `this.formAlias` is what determines whether a unique form.

So simply create new objects on the localStorage with this unique identifier

```
  onSubmit() {
    myUniqueIdentifier() {
      return 'policy' + this.formAlias; // You can amend this incase  this.formAlias isn't what you use to identify each form
    }
    this.submitted$.next(true);
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const formValuesArray: Array<any> = getFromLocalStorage(this.myUniqueIdentifier());
      formValuesArray.push(this.form.value);
      setToLocalStorage(this.myUniqueIdentifier(), formValuesArray);
      this.stepService.nextStep();
    } else {
      this.submitted = true;
    }
  }
```

At the end you will items in the localstorage prefixed with 'policy'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I said @IAfanasov solution doesn't work on my code it creates the first array but it overwrittes the same array when I submit the form again.

Comment: for your solution i get error when i submit  a form.
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: this is how my policy value looks like.

{"contactInfo":{"email":"fvreferf@gmail.com","phone":"568552255","termsConditions":true},"underageChildInfo":{"gender":"F","name":"test","surname":"test","personalNumber":"02027041738","birthDate":"2021-06-27T13:46:47.000Z"}}